# Django Password Field Not Rendering with Bootstrap Attributes

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I was trying to style my password fields in the registration of my Django Accounts App.

```
'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password','required': 'required'}, ),
'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm password','required': 'required'}, ),
```

My view renders to the *register.html* which is in the code below

```
<div class="col-12 mt-4">
    {{ form.password1 }}
</div>
<div class="col-12 mt-4">
    {{ form.password2 }}
</div>
```

But the result for the Password field is not styled as the other fields. The rendered register page is as shown below
[image: rendered register.html page]

What could be the fix to give the following output
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1):

After research, it turns out the default Django register fields i.e "username", "password1" and "password2" widgets can be tweaked at the constructor, here is the working code

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Username'
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm password'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest like this: Please try this.

**Method 1**

```
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password','required': 'required'}, ))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm password','required': 'required'}, ))
```

**Method 2**

Using constructor (Reduce code)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password','required': 'required'}
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm password','required': 'required'}
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm password','required': 'required'}
```

Comment: I was able to fix it using the constructor, turns out the default fields from django i.e username, password1 and password2 widgets can be enhanced at the constructor..Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using crispy_fields or django-crispy-forms.
I faced same issue but after that I implemented crispy-forms and resolved issue.
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/